# Visual Studio 2010 no corre el proyecto

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Lo que pasa es que en mi equipo de desarrollo se esta llevando a cabo un proyecto, se hace uso de Tortoise para mantener el repositorio actualizado. En mi laptop el proyecto no inicia, sin embargo en las computadoras de mis compañeros si. El proyecto esta ubicado siguiente directorio:

```
C:\Users\Felipe Flores\Desktop\ProyectoIntegrador\SGRO
```

además pensando en que el espacio vació en mi nombre de usuario causaba algún problema, también lo tengo en otra ubicación dentro de una partición de respaldo

```
D:\ProyectoIntegrador\SGRO
```

Sin embargo en ninguna de las dos ubicaciones anteriormente mencionadas permite correr el proyecto. También he intentado en configurar la conexión a la base de datos de forma manual mediante el entorno gráfico de visual studio, pero a la hora de testear la conexión me manda un error con el siguiente mensaje:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Viendo el mensaje decidí revisar el archivo Web.config para asegurarme que las direcciones IP de las bases de datos fueran las correctas. Y si, lo revise varias veces y estaban correctas tanto las direcciones IP como los nombres de las bases de datos y el usuario y contraseña que he estado usando.

¿Cuál puede ser el problema que esta provocando este error?

Comment: El error que mencionas ocurre cuando creas la conexion desde VS, cuando ejecutaas tu proyecto ocurre el mismo error. Con la información que nos muestras solo puedo comentarte que revises si el usuario de SQL tiene permitido la conexión desde tu IP

Comment: no puedes conectarte a la base de datos. deberias arreglar eso primero..

Comment: ¿Las credenciales que estás usando para conectarte a tu base de datos son correctas?

Comment: Felipe, Ya revisaste que el servicio MS SQL server este corriendo? @FelipeFlores

Comment: @jasilva, desde Microsoft SQL-Server 2008 puedo ingresar a la base de datos con mis credenciales y desde la misma computadora desde la cual deseo correr el proyecto en visual studio.

Comment: @gbianchi Las credenciales son las mismas con las que he probado en otras maquinas sin embargo solo en la mía es en la que no funciona.

Comment: @Jorgesys si, ya revise y  si esta corriendo el servicio de MS SQL

Comment: @FelipeFlores Una pregunta la conexión es remota o estas accediendo a una instancia SQL en tu equipo?

Comment: SQL Server se conecta por default por el puerto 1433, en tu archivo we.config revisa que después de la dirección ip de tu servidor tenga un espacio y luego el 1433, esto es para especificar que se conectará por ese puerto

Comment: Intenta reinciar el servicio de SQL Server, a ver si eso soluciona el problema

Comment: @FelipeFlores ¿Has intentado conectarte con otro cliente que no sea VS2010 desde tu PC, por ejemplo SQL Server Management Studio? Podrías editar tu pregunta e incluir la información de tu archivo de configuración (web.config) como la imagen del testeo desde tu VS2010.

Comment: @FelipeFlores, tu pregunta debería ser clara y directa. Tienes problemas de que tu proyecto no corre bien (no se ejecuta correctamente obviando la conexión a la base de datos) o que precisamente no puedes conectarte a la base de datos desde tu VS2010 u otro cliente desde tu PC.

Answer (score 0):

Por el mensaje de error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. **The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.** (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Debes de revisar primeramente :

- asegura el servicio se este ejecutando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Si aseguras esta corriendo el servicio, revisa el nombre de la instancia que trata de usar tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas ejecutando desde local (PC) y el servidor de base de datos de SQL está en tu red u otro dominio tienes que registrar tu usuario para poder acceder, ya que son temas de credenciales y permisos. El error que reportas se debe a eso.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Además, si has descargado el mismo código fuente de los que sí ejecuta, no es un tema del versionador `TortoiseSVN`.